# All dashlets display "Object Moved" after host name change

Tags: dashboard, dashlet, migration

We've changed server host name recently and all seems to be fine excluding dashlet reports disappearance: there is just "Object Moved, This document may be found here" like on this screen grab http://awesomescreenshot.com/0375gftva1

We've checked carefully all paths at:

- civicrm.settings.php
- Administer - System Settings - Directories
- Administer - System Settings - Resource URLs
- Administer - System
  Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths

Also

- Cache has been instantly cleared,
- Refresh Dashboard button used,
- each report has been enabled / disabled / updated,
- log files in ConfigAndLogs folder has been monitored,
- page has been inspected using  XHR inspector in Firefox,
- as well as server logs.

There are several suspicious messages in Drupal Watchdog though, like:

```
* undefined index: columns in CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX::dashboard() 
(line 610 of /civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php).

* $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] =>
 CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => -5 [message] => 
DB Error: already exists [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_menu 
(domain_id , path , breadcrumb ) VALUES
```

..but it's unclear how it might be relevant to this case, especially when cache has been cleared almost instantly. Any clue, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "own question - own answer" mode .. again. Well, it turned that server name resolves as **www.hostname.tld** while all paths we used were in just **hostname.tld** format.